# Datetime from API , Create/post to API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I got two different projects, one API and one for the web(front).
I Can create a course through my API but when i try to post from my front-end i got this error,

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

And it complains on this one,

```
<span asp-validation-for="CourseTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
          <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="CourseStart" class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 pb-3">
            <input asp-for="CourseStart" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="CourseStart" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
            <div class="col-2">
            <label asp-for="CourseEnd" class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 pb-3">
```

Somehow my CourseStart doesnt work, and my class looks like this,

```
 [Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CourseTitle { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime CourseStart { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime CourseEnd { get; set; }
```

The problem i think i got is that when i save a course through the API i got Date like this,

```
 "courseStart": "2022-12-15T00:00:00"
```

So i think its expecting T00:00:00 somehow? What do u think? I cant find anything on google....

Comment: Have you checked that the object you are sending over the call to your API actually contains dates?

Comment: Hmm.. strange, because im using same Models as my API. u think i have to change the Displayformat somehow? I cant find anything on the web. No tutorials or something either...

Comment: have you tried sending the date adhering to `dd/MM/yyyy`? given you had `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`.

Comment: on my front-end im getting a icon there i can choose date. And that format is in yyyy-mm-dd so it has to be the formats somehow. I will try to make it manually

Comment: Not sure which version of .NET you are using, but you might want to use `DateOnly` for this if it works.  It will eliminate the `T00:00:00` from your data. It was added in .NET 6, and I believe it should work in most parts of ASP.NET by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, what i did was,
changed my class to this,

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime CourseStart { get; set; }
```

after that, inside my html file, i put in this,

```
<div class="col-2">
     <label asp-for="CourseStart" class="control-label pt-2" style="font-size:20px;"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10 pb-3">
                <input asp-for="CourseStart" type="date"  class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CourseStart" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

problem was that, through html helper, it saved it in this format, yyyy-MM-dd, so i had to change it. U can probably customize it but its to complicated for me :)